# Regex to match everything before hypen - multiple match

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, expression

I got this string:

```
scQA00-psql11 scQA00-psql21 scQA01-psql2 scQA00-psql21
scqa00-psql01 scqa00-psql11 scqa00-psql21
```

I want to match only:

```
scQA00 scQA00 scQA01 scQA00
scqa00 scqa00 scqa00
```

I tried with: `[^-]+`
but cannot get any further than this :(

I tried also `(.*?)(?=-)+`

But it match only first occurrence.

How could i match everything before hyphen but to ignore spaces?

Comment: Forget to mention that -xxxxx could be anything not only "psqXX"

Comment: I already did that ...but cannot resolve it :(

Comment: [^-]* but cannot get any further than this :(

Comment: Please add this and other details to the question. Especially what code/commands you used.

Comment: THanks. I did now.

Comment: Sorry, not there yet. Why did you even try the Perl/PCRE `(.*?)(?=-)+` expression in *Bash*? Please add the code you used with the regex. `[^-]+` only matches one or more chars other than `-` (if used as a POSIX ERE expression).

Comment: I am trying it in; https://regex101.com/ but looks that you don't want to even help me.

Comment: because grep -E is using PCRE regex.

Comment: No, `grep -E` uses POSIX ERE. `grep -P` uses PCRE. Why do you use `grep`? I think you want to remove all substrings starting with `-` and until a whitespace/end of string.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks!

Comment: Hi there ...i found soultion: \S+(?=-) thanks!

Comment: I think you need a simpler one, `sed -E 's/-[^[:space:]]+//g' <<< "$t"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract all substrings consisting of non-whitespace chars before `-`, you may use

```
grep -Po '[^\s-]+(?=-)' file
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oq8Yaz/2). The `[^\s-]+(?=-)` pattern matches any one or more chars other than whitespace and `-`, followed with a `-`.

If you just need to remove parts of strings starting with `-` and until the next whitespace or end of string, you may use `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/-[^[:space:]]+//g' file
```

Here, `-[^[:space:]]+` matches a `-` and then one or more chars other than whitespace.

See the [online demo](http://text=%27scQA00-psql11%20scQA00-psql21%20scQA01-psql2%20scQA00-psql21%20scqa00-psql01%20scqa00-psql11%20scqa00-psql21%27%20grep%20-Po%20%27%5B%5E%5Cs-%5D+(?=-)%27%20%3C%3C%3C):

```
text='scQA00-psql11 scQA00-psql21 scQA01-psql2 scQA00-psql21
scqa00-psql01 scqa00-psql11 scqa00-psql21'
grep -Po '[^\s-]+(?=-)' <<< "$text"
# scQA00
# scQA00
# scQA01
# scQA00
# scqa00
# scqa00
# scqa00
sed -E 's/-[^[:space:]]+//g' <<< "$text"
# scQA00 scQA00 scQA01 scQA00
# scqa00 scqa00 scqa00
```